# Handling Hardware interrupts in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am working on a embedded linux platform running Linux 2.6 . I would love to know how to do the following.

1) I have a hardware interrupt source irq7 which shows up in /proc/interrupts

cat /proc/interrupts | grep IRQ7

M547X_8X  71:    1916076 PCI IRQ7

2) For PCI IRQ7, each time i press a button, 3rd value value changes

M547X_8X  71:    2177862 PCI IRQ7

Doesn't this mean my switch press is recognized?

Now i want to trigger a user program from sleep when i press this button. How do i write 
this user space program using interrupts or signal?

Should i write a driver program for this?

Can you suggest resources that i should look into?

Comment: look into doing a blocking read on a gpio node

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on gpio key on linux. After exporting the interrupt to /dev/input/eventXXX, you can use evtest tool for check from user space.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I would like to do it in C. Which library would i use? Could you please explain more?

Comment: Hi, The first thing you should learn how the button can interrupt the CPU, on SoC as usual the button is connected to one gpio pin of the CPU. When you know about the way button connect to CPU, you will find the right way to handle the interrupt. About the evtest tool, you can get it here [link(beagleboard.googlecode.com/files/evtest.c)]. it's c program.